# How can I define a function that accepts any data class which has a specific field

Tags: kotlin

For example, I want a function `foo` that accepts both `A` and `B` defined in external packages like this:

```
fun foo<T: { p: Int }>(x: T) {}

data class A(val p: Int, val a: Int)
data class B(val p: Int, val b: Int)
```

I tried Interface, but it seems to need to update the definition of A and B, but I cannot do that because they are defined in external packages.

What I want to do is like this in TypeScript:

```js
function foo(x: {p: number}) {}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike TypeScript, Kotlin does not use [structural typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system), so you can only enforce this by using an interface.

If you can't do that, then you have to ask the caller of `foo` to give you the property you nee, by taking an extra parameter

```
fun <T> foo(x: T, p: KProperty1<T, Int>) {
    println(p.get(x)) // example access
}
```

Example usage:

```
foo(A(1, 2), A::p)
```

A major difference from using an interface is that the caller can use any `Int` property on `A`. It doesn't have to be called `p`.

Other than that, your only choice would be enforcing this at runtime, by throwing exceptions when the property is not found.

Comment: Would it be more conventional to make it `p: (T)->Int` so we aren't unnecessarily involving reflection types?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I had considered that too, but since OP here wants to enforce a *property* specifically, I suggested the "stronger" `KProperty` type instead.

Comment: Ah, I see, although I think it could still be overcome by passing an extension property.